# Library not loaded libcrypto.1.1.dylib: incompatible architecture between x86_64 and arm64

Tags: mac, homebrew, apple-silicon

I have a M1 Pro laptop and have been trying to install homebrew on it. However, I'm getting incompatibilities with libcrypto, probably due to Apple Silicon architecture.

```
dyld[22223]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
Referenced from: <6A748268-51FC-32E0-AC20-D9143A012CF6> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.4.0/bin/node
Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

I've tried completely uninstalling homebrew, re-installing it, and slowly installing packages but I still ran into the same issues above. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which command do you run which triggered the error message?

Comment: In my case, I just ran `yarn`. This was after installing `nodejs`, `fish`. I installed yarn with `npm install yarn -g`

Comment: Context is important here. Seems you have installed Homebrew and some commands just fine, but yarn (or nodejs, or parts of it) have not been recompiled for ARM yet.

Comment: So nodejs doesn't work for macOS ARM at all? That seems surprising after all this time.

Comment: All we know is that whatever you installed via Homebrew doesn‘t work. The question doesn’t have enough details to prove/disprove the „doesn‘t work“ claim (but you can download an ARM version directly from nodejs.org so most likely it‘s an installation issue with OpenSSL).